# Auto-split attachment from e-mail in e-mail client at download?

Tags: email, attachment, claws

I've searched around on this for months every now and then, including here, to no avail. My issue seems so exotic I even seem unable to use the right set of keywords in forums and communities. That's why I've finally registered and am hoping somebody can give me a hand or a hint... either for a solution or for where I've overlooked what I need for months...

I switched to Linux Ubuntu about a year ago, am running 20.04 LTS and opted for Claws Mail as my e-mail client, now 3.17.5, which I'm happy with on the whole. Now here's the hiccup. Back in the old days I used Qualcomm's Eudora as my e-mail client and stuck to its last 7.x version from 2003 or so thru to 2020 because it has two niceties I absolutely adore. One, it allows e-mails to always be displayed as plain-text with no code execution, so no scripting hazards, which I am able to reproduce in Claws. And two, upon download, it splits any attachment from the body of the e-mail into a directory of my choosing and does not keep it in the e-mail as saved on my hard disk, but puts a link to the local storage into the e-mail as saved in the mailbox. With the direct-save attachment, I get the file creation date as a proof of moment of download, which I sometimes need, and it saves gigs of disk space, since I usually need to save every single attachment to disk for processing at any rate and then have it both as a download and in the e-mail. I'd really like have to have this direct-save/auto-split feature for attachments because tons of workflow steps I've used for years rely on it; but I haven't been able to tweak Claws my way, find anything on scripting pointing me the right direction, or an e-mail client for Ubuntu for that matter that gives me such a feature out of the box.

Any help appreciated, thx.

Comment: Thunderbird supports splitting out attachments. There is some info here http://kb.mozillazine.org/Attachments_(Thunderbird) that suggests it should also be possible to create a message filter that automatically saves attachments or deletes attachments as the message comes in (or when you manually run the filter over existing messages).